# Add timestamp column to file in Node.js Google Cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Right now I'm copying files on Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery using the following line in node.js:

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
bigquery.dataset(xx).table(xx).load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName));
```

But now I'd like to add a new timestamp column to this file. So how can I do this?

So two questions I could think of:
First read this file into some data structure like array:

```
array = FunctionToReadFileNameToArray(FileName);
```

Do we have such a function? Suppose we have, then it's quite easy to manipulate upon the array to add timestamp column.

Second, load the new array data into bigquery. But I only find one way to insert streaming data:

```
bigquery.dataset(xx).table(xx).insert(rows);
```

And here rows is different data structure like dictionary/map but not array. So how can we load array into bigquery?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that we can stream rows into BQ by passing in an array of rows ... here is an example ... https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have a file (Object) of structured records (JSON, XML, CSV).  The first task would appear to be opening that GCS object for reading.  You would then read one record at a time.  You would then augment that record with your desired extra column (timestamp) and then invoke the [insert()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#insert) API.  This API can take a single object to be inserted or an array of objects.

However ... if this is a one-time event or can be performed in batch ... you may find it cheaper to read the GCS object and write a new GCS object containing your desired data and THEN load the data into BQ as a unit.  Looking at the pricing for BQ, we seem to find that streaming inserts are charged at $0.01 per 200MB in addition to the storage costs which would be bypassed for a GCS object load as a unit.  My own thinking is that doing extra work to save pennies is a poor use of time/money but if you are processing TB of data over months, it may add up.